# What happens if I delete a folder from the cloned fork of a repository in GITHub

Tags: git

I have cloned a fork  into my local. I am trying to run my testcases through maven build for this part of project. I have deleted some test folders of different modules from this project to overcome test failures of them.

Now when I commit,push my changed files in this cloned fork, Does it effect to the branch XYZ of the central repository

Comment: no it does not. fork is your own copy of the original repo. It does not affect original repo

Comment: what if I do the pull request

Comment: if you do a pull request then the admins of the original repo will see your pull request and if they think that your pull request is good then they will accept and only then your changes will be reflected in the original repo

Comment: what about the deleted folders/files,can the admin come to know that about my local copy. I think the only files I have commited/pushed will be visible to them

Comment: I am afraid to say this but this is not a forum so you should not have much discussions here. I suggest you to read how git/Github works. Take some tutorials and read some docs

Answer (score 2):

No, a forked repository is a completely independent repo. The only way to make changes to the original repo is to submit a Pull Request with changes.

Anything you do to your forked repo will have no effect on the original unless you intentionally want to edit the original via a PR.

Comment: I think if I do git pull origin then some does happen